# JQuery Mobile Cloned Drop Down not cloning popup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with JQuery Mobile.  I have stripped down my code here as best I can.  I have a questionTemplate that includes a drop down and users can add new questions.  I clone the template to create a new question.  The problem seems to be, at the initial load of the page, JQuery Mobile creates some popup's for the drop down when it opens that are stylized for JQM.  In my example here I see a .  One of its children has a id called "question-type-0-menu".  So these are not being created with my clone.  Is there a way I could trigger their creation when I clone my template?

HTML

```
<div id="questionContainer">
    <select id="questionTemplate">
        <option id="question-value-1-1">Question 1</option>
        <option id="question-value-1-2">Question 2</option>
        <option id="question-value-1-3">Question 3</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <button>clone</button>
```

Javascript

```
var gOldId = 1;

$("button").click(function()
 {
    var newQuestion = $("#questionTemplate").clone( true, true ).removeAttr("id");

    var newId = $("#questionContainer > *").length + 1;

    // Change ids of clone
    newQuestion.find('[id]').each(function(index)
    {
        var placeholderString = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', placeholderString.replace( gOldId, newId ));


        //alert( 'id' + $(this).attr('id') );
    });

     newQuestion.data("data-native-menu", "false");

     gOldId = newId; // Update id


    newQuestion.appendTo( $("#questionContainer") );
 });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Nc3A7/?

Comment: It does seem odd that the clones are not styled correctly in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a "simple" clone of the element and not a with data and events, and than if you manually apply selectmenu plugin to new elements the code works fine.

You can use: `$(<selector>).selectmenu();`

Code:

```
var gOldId = 1;

$("#clone").click(function () {
    var newQuestion = $("#questionTemplate").clone().removeAttr("id");

    var newId = $("#questionContainer > *").length + 1;

    // Change ids of clone
    newQuestion.find('[id]').each(function (index) {
        var placeholderString = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', placeholderString.replace(gOldId, newId));


        //alert( 'id' + $(this).attr('id') );
    });

    newQuestion.data("data-native-menu", "false");

    gOldId = newId; // Update id

    newQuestion.appendTo($("#questionContainer"));

    newQuestion.selectmenu();
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/clone/ and http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Nc3A7/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Not in the code I had but the IDs of the clone were always incorrect, even after I updated them.  I got around this by doing a .load(*.php) into the div instead.